# Problems using widetext.sty

Tags: equations, two-column

I need to prepare a document for a journal and I'm using the `twocolumn` option in the `article` class. Now I have a horrible equation that makes use of the `cases` environment so it's hard to split up to make it fit into one column. I do not want to use the `figure*` environment because I have no control over where to put the equation.

What I want to do is to use the `widetext` package and make sure that this equation looks something like it would like when one uses `revtex4`. However, when compiling my document I get an error, namely "improper `\prevdepth`". Does anyone have a clue what I have to do here?

A minimum working example (using the actual formula)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{widetext}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{cuted}

\begin{document}

a lot of text ...


Here
\begin{widetext}
\begin{eqnarray} \label{e27}
T_{nn''}^{mm''}=({-}1)^{p-p''}\,\dil_0^{\infty}\,J_{m-m''}(au)\,J_{n''}(bu)\,J_{n+1}(u)\,du~=
\begin{cases}
& \dfrac{(q{+}p'')!\,(p{-}p'')!}{(q{-}q'')!\,(p{+}q'')!}\,a^{m-m''}b^{n''}\,P_{p-p''}^{(m-m'',n'')}(1{-}2A^2)P_{p-p''}^{(m-m'',n'')}(2B^2{-}1)~~~ \\ & \text{when}~~~n-n''\geq m-m''\geq0~,\\
\\
& \dfrac{(p{+}q'')!\,(q{-}q'')!}{(p{-}p'')!\,(q{+}p'')!}\,a^{m''-m}b^{n''}\,P_{q-q''}^{(m''-m,n'')}(1{-}2A^2)\,P_{q-q''}^{(m''-m,n'')}(2B^2{-}1)~~~ \\ & \text{when}~~~ n-n''\geq m''-m\geq0~, \\
\\
&0 ~~~ \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}
\end{widetext}

a lot more text....
\end{document}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

This works:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{widetext}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{cuted}

\begin{document}

a lot of text ...

Here
\begin{widetext}
\begin{equation} \label{e27}
\begin{aligned}
&T_{nn''}^{mm''}=({-}1)^{p-p''}\,d_0^{\infty}\,J_{m-m''}(au)\,J_{n''}(bu)\,J_{n+1}(u)\,du = \\
&\qquad\begin{cases}
& \dfrac{(q{+}p'')!\,(p{-}p'')!}{(q{-}q'')!\,(p{+}q'')!}\,a^{m-m''}b^{n''}\,P_{p-p''}^{(m-m'',n'')}
(1{-}2A^2)P_{p-p''}^{(m-m'',n'')}(2B^2{-}1) \\ 
& \text{when}~~~n-n''\geq m-m''\geq0~,\\
\\
& \dfrac{(p{+}q'')!\,(q{-}q'')!}{(p{-}p'')!\,(q{+}p'')!}\,a^{m''-m}b^{n''}\,P_{q-q''}^{(m''-m,n'')}
(1{-}2A^2)\,P_{q-q''}^{(m''-m,n'')}(2B^2{-}1)~~~ \\ 
& \text{when}~~~ n-n''\geq m''-m\geq0~, \\
\\
&0\text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{widetext}

a lot more text....
\end{document}
```

[image]

The version used of `widetext.sty` has been downloaded from

https://svn.einsteintoolkit.org/documents/Paper_EinsteinToolkit_2010/widetext.sty

Comment: This example works for me, but only if I either (1) insert a blank line before `\begin{widetext}` or (2) make the "Here" paragraph longer; otherwise I still get `\prevdepth` errors. Could this just be weirdness with my setup, or did you run into anything like this? On a related note, I've seen several forum suggestions for inserting a blank line before `\begin{strip}` in this widetext.sty, which helps *sometimes* for me.

Comment: works nicely with epj templates.

Comment: Is `widetext` still part of TeXLive? I have `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)` and `widetext` doesn't work with `article`. I get `! LaTeX Error: Environment widetext undefined.`.

Comment: @alfC I don't think it has ever been in TeX Live.

Answer (score 3):

*I'm rewriting my answer because my previous one was actually wrong. I apologize if it wasted anybody's time.*

I also got error messages related to `\prevdepth`. The problem seems to arise in the `strip` environment used within `widetext`.

The error message states `\prevdepth` cannot work in horizontal mode. As Chris White noted, adding a newline solves it since (I guess) it puts TeX in vertical mode.

In order to get it work, I modified `widetext.sty`, to start a new paragraph before the `strip` environment and corrected the vertical space to avoid an empty line in second column, as follows:

```
...
\if@twocolumn
    \newenvironment{widetext}
    {%
        \par \vspace{-\baselineskip} % <-- this line added
        \begin{strip}

       ...

        \end{strip}
    \par \vspace{-\baselineskip}\noindent % <-- this line added
    \hspace*{-\parindent} % <-- this line added
    }
 ...
```

I had to add these two lines at the end to prevent extra indentation at the first paragraph after `widetext`, the origin of which I don't know.

See if it works for you.

Comment: I would favour some commands provided by package `etoolbox`, see for “Environment Hooks” in documentation. Also: The package `cuted`, to whome the environment `strip` belongs, provides a glue length `\stripsep`, what can be changed. See in according documentation, as well.