# Long equation spanning two columns in Elsevier template

Tags: equations, elsarticle

I am writing a paper using Elsevier template which has two columns format. How can I write an equation that spans over the two columns?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151365/15925 help?  If not please add an example of what you are doing and what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[5p,preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools, cuted}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}


\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{strip}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{q_\mathrm{tot}=0}^{Q_A+Q_B-2}\sum_{q_A=0}^{q_\mathrm{tot}}{\textstyle\binom{Q_A-1}{q_A}\binom{Q_B-1}{q_B}}x^{q_\mathrm{tot}},
\end{equation}
\end{strip}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Hopes this is what you are looking.