# `widetext` doesn't play nicely with the `osa-article` documentclass; are there alternatives?

Tags: environments, document-classes

I'm writing a manuscript for publication in one of Optica's journals, so I'm required to use the `osa-article` documentclass. I have a very long equation which can't be broken up into several lines. I've tried using the `widetext` and `split` environments. My problem is that I like the rules added by `widetext` (gasp!) but only `split` works as expected. (Edit: `split` doesn't work with `osa-article` either.)

Here are two MWEs using `widetext`, one using `revtex4-1` and one using `osa-article`, with screenshots of the output:

**RevTeX:**

```
\documentclass[reprint]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{widetext}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{20}n=1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20=210.
\end{equation}
\end{widetext}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**OSA-Article:**

```
\documentclass{osa-article}
\journal{osajournal}

\usepackage{widetext}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{widetext}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{20}n=1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20=210.
\end{equation}
\end{widetext}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Compilation using `osa-article` requires a bunch of additional files which can be found on Optica's website. I don't know whether I'm legally allowed to share them here, and I'm too lazy to go looking. It also requires the `widetext.sty` document to be downloaded and placed in the same folder as the TeX file.)

I've tried [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61295/problems-using-widetext-sty) (the second one), which didn't work for me; all it did was add a rule under the equation, but otherwise it still looks like the screenshot above.

The `revtex4-1` output is what I'd like to have. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I’d use a `table*` environment

Comment: Thanks, @egreg. I tried that and it didn't work. Turns out `split` isn't working properly either (same result as `widetext`). I'm guessing I'd still need to create a wide environment inside which the `table*` goes...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using cuted package instead of widetext would help. You can add rules manually if you like.

```
\documentclass{osa-article}
\journal{osajournal}

\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{strip}
    \rule{\dimexpr(0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep-0.4pt)}{0.4pt}%
    \begin{equation}
        \sum_{n=1}^{20}n=1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20=210.
    \end{equation}
    \par
    \hfill
    \rule[0.5\baselineskip]{\dimexpr(0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep-1pt)}{0.4pt}
\end{strip}
          
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I was trying `cuted` with `split`; I didn't know about `strip`. Thank you!